# Reduce the webpart zone width

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint online and the SharePoint designer does not have a visual interface like in on-prem . I need to be able to get the web part id to edit the css and make the width smaller.

How do I search for the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Developer tools in your browser for that.

Open the page in your browser and hit F12. In IE (other browsers work similar) go to the tab 'DOM Explorer'. In the upper left corner you will find an icon with a box and an arrow. Click it once and then hover your mouse over the web part in question and click again. This will open the corresponding node in the DOM Explorer. From there on it should be easy to find the ID of the element containing your webpart.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did and got the div id named ms-rte-layoutszone-inner and added the below css in the script editor #ms-rte-layoutszone-inner
{
 width: 40px;
overflow: auto;
}
some how i cant  get the size any smaller

Comment: Which layout are you using and which zone do you want to reduce to which size?

Comment: i am using 3 vertical once i want to reduce the middle one

Comment: The ms-rte-layoutszone-inner is surrounded by a TR with class ms-wiki-columnSpacing which has quite a bit of padding. You would have to reduce/remove that padding to reduce the width further.

Comment: Tried it , thats not it  see the code i used  below <script>
#ms-wiki-columnSpacing{
 width: 40px;
overflow: auto;
}
</script>

Comment: ms-wiki-columnSpacing is a Class not an ID. In order to target a Class you will have to use a . instead of # ( .ms-wiki-columnSpacing {...} ). And then, again, you might have to reduce/remove the padding in order to make it smaller.

Comment: it's not the one mate, all i want is to put a single line in between two webpart and sharepoint designer in sharepoint online does not show the design view as it used to.

Comment: How about you show what you have and what you want to achieve with some screenshots/mockups?

Comment: But better open a new question for that. And if my original answer answered your original question sufficiently, I'd be happy if you could mark it as answer.